# Automatic replies with dovecot and pigeonhole

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I would like to send automatic replies to e-mails with certain characteristics
and it seems that the dovecot pigeonhole plugin can do this, but I'm confused
about what I need to get it to work.  I now use fdm to fetch mail into
`~/mail/spool/` and dovecot to make it available to Gnus.  This is my
`/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`:

```
mail_location = maildir:%h/mail:LAYOUT=fs:INBOX=%h/mail/spool
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Now I've tried various things that lay floating on the Internet to get
pigeonhole to work, but the  dovecot documentation claims that pigeonhole
requires lda or lmtp, and, as far as I can see, these are for getting mail from
a "mail transfer agent" (such as postfix) and not from a maildir.  Does that
mean I cannot use pigeonhole to deliver stuff from `~/mail/spool/` to other
maildirs and send automatic replies?  There is sieve-filter, which can be used
manually, but the part of it that would take care of automatic replies (`-q`
and `-Q`) is not yet implemented.